# Recursive function to stop when n-th nested array has no more nested arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have JSON document which has some nested arrays. And I want to make `function AAA()` which recalls every time if an array has nested array. And then stop when there isn't more nested arrays.

For example. If I have:

```
         array[AAA,BBB,CCC]
                |
               AAA[AAA,BBB,CCC]
                    |
                   AAA[AAA,BBB,CCC]
                        |
                       etc.
```

I want to call `function AAA()` always when `AAA` has a subarray. Let's say `AAA` has 5 times `subAAA`. I want the `function(AAA)` to call itself 5 times and then stop. And if in future I add more subarrays to call more times.

If it will help here is my `.json`:

```
{
    "navigation" : [

        {
            "name" : "home",
            "href" : "home.html"    
        },

        {
            "name" : "services",
            "href" : "interior.html",
            "navigation" : [
                {
                    "name" : "PROJECT MANAGEMENT",
                    "href" : "interior.html",
                    "navigation" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "PROJECT MANAGEMENT",
                                "href" : "interior.html"
                            },
                            {
                                "name" : "BUSINESS ANALYST",
                                "href" : "interior.html"
                            }
                        ]
                },
                {
                    "name" : "BUSINESS ANALYST",
                    "href" : "interior.html"
                }
            ]
        },

        {
            "name" : "company",
            "href" : "home.html"    
        }


    ]
}
```

And the js code is:

```
function parseJSON(){

        var navigation = new_json['navigation'];
        var nav_html = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < navigation.length; i++) {

            var name = navigation[i]['name'];
            var href = navigation[i]['href'];
            var submenu = navigation[i]['navigation'];

            nav_html += '<li><a href="' + href + '">' + name + '<span class="ddArrow"></span></a>';     

            if( typeof(submenu) != 'undefined' ){
                nav_html += '<ul>';

                for( var j=0; j<submenu.length; j++ ){

                    var submenu_name = submenu[j]['name'];
                    var submenu_href = submenu[j]['href'];

                    nav_html += '<li><a href="' + submenu_href + '">' + submenu_name + '</a></li>';         
                }
                nav_html += '</ul>';
            }
            nav_html += '</li>';
            console.log( nav_html );
            $('#navigation ul').html( nav_html );
        };  
    };
```

That way I want to create navigation which has submenus. Now I have 3 levels, but if I decide to add 4th and 5th. I want my code to parse them in the HTML without writing more code. I have the rest ... I just need to the `IF` when function stops.

I simply don't write what I have tried because I understand why is not working.

Comment: It seems obvious that it should stop recursing whenever `navigation` is no longer a property or an empty array. What exactly is the problem and where's your code?

Comment: Please show  us what you have so far, otherwise we can't help you integrating the condition into your code.

Comment: As you mentioned in the title, you need a recursive function. So why is yours not recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive function is quite simple to build, and is very similar to the code you already have:

```
function parseJSON() {
    function makeList(navigation) {
        var nav_html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < navigation.length; i++) {
            var name = navigation[i]['name'],
                href = navigation[i]['href'],
                submenu = navigation[i]['navigation'];

            nav_html += '<li><a href="' + href + '">' + name + '<span class="ddArrow"></span></a>';     

            if( typeof(submenu) != 'undefined' ){
                nav_html += '<ul>';
                // now here, do not iterate it again!
                // call the function recursively!
                nav_html += makeList(submenu);
                nav_html += '</ul>';
            }
            nav_html += '</li>';
        }
        return nav_html;
    }
    $('#navigation ul').html( makeList( new_json['navigation'] ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right in thinking that it only needs to run again if it contains a navigation property, you could just use:

```
// Without using Array.forEach. Array.isArray polyfill may be 
// required to support older browsers.
function getLinks(obj) {
    var i, len;
    if (Array.isArray(obj.navigation)) {
        len = obj.navigation.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
            getLinks(obj.navigation[i]);
        }
    }
}

// Using Array.forEach - Polyfill may be required using the 
// forEach method to support older browsers.
function getLinks(obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj.navigation)) {
        obj.navigation.forEach(function (link) {
            getLinks(link);
        });
    }
}

// Array.isArray polyfill.
if(!Array.isArray) {
    Array.isArray = function (vArg) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(vArg) === "[object Array]";
    };
}

// Array.forEach polyfill.
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
        for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
            fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
        }
    }
}
```

[isArray polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)
[forEach polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)