# Why I need to use 2 functions, but not only one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I paste all of my code because it might have a connection with the function I am asking for. I had help to make one of my functions run. Look at the `parseJSON()` function. Why I have to use 2 functions (`parseJSON()` and nested `makeNav(navigation)`), but not only one `parseJSON(navigation)` (and ofc to change the inner elements from makeNav to parseJSON). Can someone explain why it works only that way for me. Because I want to understand it, not just to do my exercise and go on.

```
    var new_json;
    $.get('navigation.json', function (json){
        new_json = json;
        parseJSON();

        var reload_page;
        var this_hash = window.location.hash;

        if( this_hash.length == 0 ){
            reload_page = "home";
        }else{
            reload_page = this_hash.replace('#', '');
        };

        loading(reload_page + '.html');
    });

    var cache = {};

    function loading(url){


        if( typeof(cache[url]) == 'undefined' ) {
            console.log( 'cache A does not exists' );

            container.load(url + ' .container>*', function(){

                cache[url] = container.html();          
            });
        }else {
            console.log( 'cache A exists' );

            container.html(cache[url]);
        };
    };

    $('#navigation li a, #logo a').live('click',function(){

        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        window.location.hash = url.replace('.html', '');

        loading(url);

        return false;
    });




    function parseJSON() {

        function makeNav(navigation) {
            var nav_html = '';
            console.log( navigation.length );
            for (var i = 0; i < navigation.length; i++) {
                var name = navigation[i]['name'];
                var href = navigation[i]['href'];
                var submenu = navigation[i]['navigation'];

                nav_html += '<li><a href="' + href + '">' + name + '<span class="ddArrow"></span></a>';     

                if( typeof(submenu) != 'undefined' ){
                    nav_html += '<ul>';
                    nav_html += makeNav(submenu);
                    nav_html += '</ul>';
                }
                nav_html += '</li>';
            }
            return nav_html;
        }
        $('#navigation ul').html(makeNav( new_json['navigation'] ));
    }
```

Comment: If this is working code, this should be posted at `http://codereview.stackexchange.com/`

Comment: I am sorry I didn't know that .. can I move it somehow or moderator to do it ?

Comment: No problem, I don't know whether this question can be moved, or not. Probably it can by someone with enough reputation... You can always create a new question there and close this one :)

Comment: This question should be a comment on my answer to [Recursive function to stop when n-th nested array has no more nested arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381253/recursive-function-to-stop-when-n-th-nested-array-has-no-more-nested-arrays)

Comment: @Панайот: do you understand recursion?

Comment: Yes I did, but i didn't understand only why it is with 2 functions. If the parseJSON() is only to parse the new HTML, isn't there some way to do it with 1 function only. P.S.: I didn't comment your answer because I didn't know you'll be here today and I needed an answer :)

Comment: I've refactored the code a little to use a single function instead nested once. I cant guarantee that it'll work properly because I'm not sure about the JSON format, but should be something like that.

Comment: @2pietjuh2: "understanding code snippets" are off-topic on Code Review SE (according to the FAQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probable reason is that your `parseJSON` does extra things: `$('#navigation ul').html(makeNav( new_json['navigation']));` and when you make recursive call to `makeNav` you don't need to set this html content. Reason for the nested definition of `makeNav` inside `parseJSON` could be that you don't want `makeNav` to be visible outside of the scope of `parseJSON` because you simply don't use it out of this scope and you don't want to pollute the "environment".

Anyway, I really don't think that's the best way to implement it...but that should be discussed at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

To use a single function, without the nested `makeNav` you can do something like:

```
var new_json;
$.get('navigation.json', function (json){
    new_json = json;
    parseJSON();

    var reload_page;
    var this_hash = window.location.hash;

    if( this_hash.length == 0 ){
        reload_page = "home";
    }else{
        reload_page = this_hash.replace('#', '');
    };
    loading(reload_page + '.html');
});

var cache = {};

function loading(url){
    if( typeof(cache[url]) == 'undefined' ) {
        console.log( 'cache A does not exists' );
        container.load(url + ' .container>*', function(){
                cache[url] = container.html();          
        });
    }else {
        console.log( 'cache A exists' );
        container.html(cache[url]);
    };
};

$('#navigation li a, #logo a').live('click',function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location.hash = url.replace('.html', '');
    loading(url);
    return false;
});




function makeNav(navigation) {
    var nav_html = '';
    console.log( navigation.length );
    for (var i = 0; i < navigation.length; i++) {
        var name = navigation[i]['name'];
        var href = navigation[i]['href'];
        var submenu = navigation[i]['navigation'];

        nav_html += '<li><a href="' + href + '">' + name + '<span class="ddArrow"></span></a>';     

        if( typeof(submenu) != 'undefined' ){
            nav_html += '<ul>';
            nav_html += makeNav(submenu);
            nav_html += '</ul>';
        }
        nav_html += '</li>';
    }
    return nav_html;
}
```